Multiparticle relativistic quantum mechanical theory which includes creation and annihilation of particles?
While studying quantum field theory, I ran across the following question about motivating the use of quantum fields. I know the following two facts (if any of them are flawed, do let me know) -

In non-relativistic quantum mechanics, we can have theories which describe creation and annihilation of particles.
Single-particle relativistic quantum mechanics exists, and is described by the Klein-Gordon equation and Dirac equation.

However, I have not heard any mention of a multi-particle relativistic quantum mechanical theory which can handle creation and annihilation of particles. Adding to this, all the quantum field theory textbooks I've seen seem to insinuate that the only way to deal with multi-particle relativistic quantum theories which includes creation and annihilation of particles is via quantum field theory.
So, I have two related questions -

Do there exist multi-particle relativistic quantum theories which can handle creation and annihilation of particles and is not equivalent to a quantum field theory?
If there do not exist such theories, that means that all such multi-particle relativistic quantum theories which can handle creation and annihilation of particles are equivalent to quantum field theories. Where can I find a proof of the same?


Weinberg vol 1 is a standard reference for the approach "relativistic quantum mechanics implies QFT". Also I wouldn't say that single-particle relativistic QM exists. There are all sorts of well-known problems with Dirac or Klein-Gordon equations.

Relativistic quantum field theories as they are currently used implement three  sets of assumptions:

Quantum mechanics: unitary evolution of states or observables, square amplitudes that can be superposed and obey the rules of probability under decoherence.
Lorentz invariance.
Clustering: the scattering amplitude for particles in distinct, finite spatial regions should approach the product of the scattering amplitudes of particles in each region as the distance between them tends to infinity.

For a detailed explanation of this see "The Conceptual Framework of Quantum Field Theory" by Anthony Duncan, starting in Chapter 3.
An introduction to quantum field theory that is easier to read and explains some of the problems with explaining relativistic quantum theory in terms of particles can be found in "Quantum field theory for the gifted amateur" by Lancaster and Blundell, especially Chapter 8.

Multi-time wave functions
There exists an active research on so-called multi-time wave functions. They are a relativistic version of multi-particle wave functions. In non-relativistic quantum mechanics, the many particle wave function depends on $n$ space-variables and a single time variable:
$$
\Psi(t, \vec x_1, \dots, \vec x_n)
$$
Now the reference to the single time parameter $t$ makes the wave function a pretty nonrelativistic object (What would be the Lorenz transformation of the wave function).
The idea of multi-time wave functions (that goes back to Dirac) is to define wave function for space-like configurations of space time points
$$
\Psi(x_1,\dots,x_n)
$$
for all configurations $(x_1,\dots,x_n) \in \mathbb M^n$ such that either $x_i = x_j$ or $(x_i -x_j)^\mu - (x_i -x_j)_\mu >0$ (for $(-+++)$ signature). In other words, the wave function also depends on $n$-time variables (on for each particle). One can also describe particle emission and absorption, by introducing wave function for different particle numbers, i.e $\forall n \in \mathbb N_0$ we have a wave function
$$
\Psi^{(n)}(x_1, \dots, x_n)
$$
The wave equations can then relate different sectors causing emission and absorption.
For an introduction to multi-time wave functions, see: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-60691-6
A treatment of particle creation and annihilation can be found in  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.0802
Equivalence to QFT?
The question of equivalence to usual QFT is a difficult one. Because most of QFT is mathematically ill defined on a rigorous level, it is difficult to set up rigorous equations  for multi-time wave functions that reproduce the quantum field theory. In general, the framework is very different. For multi-time wave functions, the explicit wave function and the Born rule on configurations space a central. In QFT the central objects are an abstract Hilbert space and a collection of operators (called quantum fields), together with a unitary representation of the Poincaré group.
There are some rigorous results for multi-time wave functions. See e.g., the phd thesis by Lukas Nickel
https://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~deckert/publications/Dr_Nickel_Lukas.pdf
